# What libraries are installed in Robotframework?

Tags: python, pip, robotframework, libraries

i want to find what libraries are installed in Robotframework. Maybe like with a pip command or something similar. Do you know any way for doing this? I already checked the documentation but could not find this. Many thanks !

Comment: "are installed _in_"? Do you mean "are installed _with_" or "are _dependencies of_"?

Comment: All of them, like a list or something similar.

Comment: Are you asking for just the ones that came installed when you installed robot, or for all libraries that are currently installed -- both built-in and third-party? Do you just want the list, or do you want a keyword that gives you this information?

Comment: Yes, all currently installed. I got a new machine with everything preinstalled but i don`t know which libraries were included. I could just install (again) everything i need but i was curious how can you get this info. I would like the list or maybe just where to look. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there's no way to know all of the robot framework libraries that have been installed. All of the built-in libraries are easy to determine, but it's impossible to know what other libraries are there since they each get installed in their own folder.

Assuming that the libraries all follow the common pattern of "robotframework-_libraryname", you can grep the output of `pip freeze` (eg: `pip freeze | fgrep robotframework-`. Though, if you have a library that doesn't follow that convention then it may go undetected.

Comment: Thank you Bryan. I just reinstalled everything i needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use Below Command In Command Prompt

```
pip list
```